# Derivations of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that Der$(\mathbb{Q}) = \{ 0 \}$, where Der($R)$, $R$ a commutative ring, is the set of endomorphisms $\varphi: R \rightarrow R$ such that $\varphi(x \cdot y) = y \cdot \varphi(x) + x \cdot \varphi(y)$ for all $x,y \in R$.

Now clearly $\{ 0 \} \subseteq$ Der$(\mathbb{Q})$. My problem is showing the containment in the other direction. If I let $\varphi$ be any endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\varphi \in$  Der$(\mathbb{Q}) $ and I took elements $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, why is it that $\varphi(x \cdot y) = y \cdot \varphi(x) + x \cdot \varphi(y) = 0$. Here $0$ refers to the $0$ mapping.

Comment: Consider $\varphi (1\cdot 1).$

Comment: $\varphi( 1 \cdot 1) =  1 \cdot \varphi(1) + 1 \cdot \varphi (1) $. What am i looking for exactly?

Comment: Don't stop. You get $\varphi (1)=0$ from it. Now you can either work with the request that $\varphi $ is $\mathbb{Q}$ linear, or simply extent it to the natural numbers, then the integers and at last the quotients.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivations are usually defined with a notion of "scalars," e.g. $k$-derivations of a $k$-algebra $R$.

At the very least, the scalars of any derivation will include $\mathbb{Z}$ (or the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $R$, the "prime subring" integer multiples of 1), i.e. $\phi(\{n\cdot1 : n\in\mathbb{Z}\})=0$.  In the case at hand, this extends to the prime subfield $\mathbb{Q}$
$$
0=\phi(p)=\phi(pq/q)=q\phi(p/q)+\phi(q)p/q \Longrightarrow \phi(p/q)=0.
$$